# looking for a function like break that include the last element

Tags: haskell

Something that should be easy but somehow I don't find how to do it... let's have the following string: `"0@workspace_command-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"`

the section `0@workspace_command` can be something else but will never contain a '-',  I want a function that returns the following result : `["0@workspace_command-","7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"]` , all the functions that I have found give me the following result : `["0@workspace_command","-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"]`...

Comment: Hypothesis: you reach for `break` because you are used to other languages where doing real parsing into a proper data type is a pain. But Haskell makes defining custom-tailored data types a single-line pleasantry, and with parser combinator libraries, the programmer burden of proper parsing is very light -- lighter than the burden of consuming the unstructured types you get from `break` and friends. Consider adjusting your habits accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of the kind of approach I advocate in my comment above, to show how lightweight it can be. I'll use [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) for my parser combinators; a similar approach (with some tweaks) will work with other combinator libraries. I'll also use the [uuid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid) package. So, the boilerplate:

```
import Data.List
import Data.UUID
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Text.Regex.Applicative.Common
```

A custom-tailored type (I picked a name without really knowing what these are for):

```
data IndexedCmd = IndexedCmd
    { index :: Int
    , command :: String
    , uuid :: UUID
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

If we can get our hands on one of these, it offers a lot of features that your `break` version doesn't, and didn't require much code to cook up. Here's how we build one. We need to build a parser for `UUID`s first:

```
hexDigitAsChar :: RE Char Char
hexDigitAsChar = psym $ \c -> or
    [ '0' <= c && c <= '9'
    , 'a' <= c && c <= 'f'
    , 'A' <= c && c <= 'F'
    ]

parseUUID :: RE Char UUID
parseUUID = id
    . fmap read
    . sequenceA
    . intercalate [sym '-']
    $ [replicate n hexDigitAsChar | n <- [8,4,4,4,12]]
```

Once we have that in place, our parser for `IndexedCmd`s is short and sweet:

```
parseIndexedCmd :: RE Char IndexedCmd
parseIndexedCmd = pure IndexedCmd
    <*> decimal <* sym '@'
    <*> many anySym <* sym '-'
    <*> parseUUID
```

That's the whole development. It's a bit longer than the other answers, but it also does a lot more, including a lot of work that you would probably want to do anyway even if you had the exact variant of `break` that you want. For example, it extracts a structured representation of the `0@workspace_command-` prefix; and it checks that the UUID is in the right format, a task that is so annoying to do with bare `Data.List` functions that I would probably tire of writing the code and skip it entirely if I were doing this without parser combinators.

We can now use `match` to parse a single string if we want:

```
> match parseIndexedCmd "0@workspace_command-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"
Just (IndexedCmd {index = 0, command = "workspace_command", uuid = 7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c})
```

As a side bonus, we can now even handle commands which have dashes in them, an effect that would be very tedious indeed to replicate using `break` as our primitive:

```
> match parseIndexedCmd "0@workspace-command-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"
Just (IndexedCmd {index = 0, command = "workspace-command", uuid = 7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c})
```

We can also continue our development and embed this parser in a larger one for entire files full of these strings or as part of some other structured file format.

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as anything Daniel Wagner has in mind, but something like this might do in a pinch:

```
import Data.Bifunctor

breakAfterDash :: String -> (String, String)
breakAfterDash x = bimap (++ "-") tail $ break (== '-') x
```

Demo:

```
> breakAfterDash "0@workspace_command-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"
("0@workspace_command-","7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c")
```

---

But then, Daniel Wagner does have a point, so alternatively, something like might get you started on the built-in parser combinator library:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

parseOnDash :: ReadP String
parseOnDash = (++) <$> munch (/= '-') <*> string "-"
```

This is a parser that parses any character that's *not* `'-'`, then it 'parses' the string `"-"`.

Using it might be as simple as this:

```
> readP_to_S parseOnDash "0@workspace_command-7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c"
[("0@workspace_command-","7a86cb8b-0987-fe40-61f2-42b0f6fc3e1c")]
```

Notice that `readP_to_S` returns a list of results, because parsing could fail, or return more than a single match. It's up to you to determine how you want to deal with ambiguous results.

Comment: And if you compare the result of `breakAfterDash "look ma, no dash!"` (wrong answer, and throws an exception that can't be caught in pure code) to the result of `readP_to_S parseOnDash "look ma, no dash!"` (error reported by returning zero results) you'll start to see why `break` maybe isn't so convenient after all...