# Pattern Matching timestamp string

Tags: haskell

So, I have a .srt file, which is a subtitles file of the form:

```
1
00:00:01,230 --> 00:00:02,360
This is a subtitle

2
00:00:03,124 --> 00:00:04,400
This is another subtitle
```

And I need to modify it a little bit. One of the things I need to do is check the integrity of the timestamps, so I was trying to write a function in haskell to check if a string is a valid timestamp

```
data TimeStamp = TimeStamp Int Int Int Int deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

getTimeStamp :: String -> TimeStamp
getTimeStamp a = read a

isNum :: Maybe Int -> Bool
isNum x = isJust x

isTimeStamp :: String -> Bool
isTimeStamp "" = False
isTimeStamp (hour:':':min:':':sec:',':mil:_) = if (isNum numH) && (isNum numM) && (isNum numS) && (isNum numMil) then True else False
            where numH   = readMaybe [hour] :: Maybe Int
                  numM   = readMaybe [min] ::  Maybe Int
                  numS   = readMaybe [sec] ::  Maybe Int
                  numMil = readMaybe [mil] ::  Maybe Int
```

The problem is, my pattern matching doesn't work. I'm not really sure how I should pattern match substrings... Any help?

Comment: Use alex+happy, or one of the many excellent parser combinator libraries. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52556531/791604) for some discussion of why this is a superior approach to basic recursion or basic `String`-processing functions. I'm tempted to mark this as a duplicate, since my answer is basically the same to both questions, differing only in the exact language being parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in general it is true that using a parser combinator library is something you can't go wrong with. However, I don't think there is anything wrong in doing this with a simple manually rolled approach if, for example, you know for sure that the timestamps have to follow a very strict specification (and otherwise they wouldn't be valid). So in the interest of answering your actual question, there are actually a few things wrong with your code, but specifically your pattern matching:

`isTimeStamp (hour:':':min:':':sec:',':mil:_)`

Doesn't match what you think it does, cause the `min` , `sec` and `mil` match *one* character.. if you changed this to:

`isTimeStamp (hour:':':min1:min2:':':sec1:sec2:',':mil1:mil2:mil3:_)`

You'd get that pattern matching working for your timestamps..

Your second problem is with that your pattern matches are not exhaustive.. you probably want to change that match on "" and match `_` and change their order of course, thus:

```
isTimeStamp :: String -> Bool
isTimeStamp (hour:':':min1:min2:':':sec1:sec2:',':mil1:mil2:mil3:"") =   
isTimeStamp _ = False
```

After this I would suggest using a `Maybe` monad for your checks.. something like:

```
data TimeStamp = TimeStamp Int Int Int Int deriving Show

getTimeStamp :: String -> Maybe TimeStamp
getTimeStamp (hour:':':min1:min2:':':sec1:sec2:',':mil1:mil2:mil3:_) = do
    h   <- readMaybe $ hour:""
    m   <- readMaybe $ min1:min2:""
    s   <- readMaybe $ sec1:sec2:""
    mil <- readMaybe $ mil1:mil2:mil3:""
    return $ TimeStamp h m s mil
isTimeStamp _ = Nothing
```

But then after this you probably would realize that what you really want is making `TimeStamp` an instance of the `Read` and `Show` classes, so you can `show`it or `read`it .. (or yes.. `readMaybe`it) :-)

Comment: I think we also need `hour1:hour2:...`, given the OP's sample data.