# How can I concisely match a list according to its latter half, and bind it's former half accordingly?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a function `f :: String -> String` and want to match arguments of the form

```
_ ++ "bar"
```

where `_` is an unspecified string that I would like to return. In other words, I want to match arguments like `foobar` and `bazbar` and return `foo` and `baz` respectively.

Using `ViewPatterns` this is possible as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

f :: String -> String
f x@(reverse . take 3 $ reverse -> "bar") = take (n-3) x
    where n = length x
```

...but this is far from ideal. Mainly because things will get hairy very quickly if I decide that I want to combine two or more such patterns.

Ideally, I want something to be able to write something like this:

```
f (x:"bar") = x
```

but unfortunately this is not valid Haskell.

Is there an adequate solution in ViewPatterns or another extension?

Comment: How about a regex? They can contain end string anchors and you can just match the initial segment something like "(.*)bar$"

Comment: I was not aware of regex in Haskell. What would that look like?

Comment: Perhaps it is time to write an actual parser. (I bet you're asking this because it's part of a larger piece of code that's actually doing parsing anyway.) [See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52556531/791604)

Comment: To open a window into the depth of this problem: what does `f (x ++ y) = (x,y)` compute?

Answer (score 3):

On built-in `String`, this is a very bad idea, since your pattern match turns out to be quite expensive. On other string types, like `Text` or `ByteString`, you can use pattern guards:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T

f :: Text -> Text
f x | Just x' <- T.stripSuffix "bar" x = ...
```

Or with `ViewPatterns` (of which I am less fond):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ViewPatterns #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T

f :: Text -> Text
f (T.stripSuffix "bar" -> Just x') = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stripSuffix :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
stripSuffix needle = go <*> drop (length needle)
  where
    go xs [] = if xs == needle then Just [] else Nothing
    go (x:xs) (_:ys) = (x:) <$> go xs ys

f (stripSuffix "bar" -> Just pref) = pref
```

I haven't tested it too much but this is a simple solution that doesn't bring in extra machinery of regexs / parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with pattern matching. Pattern matches are typically cheap and match the structure of the input data. This is a very expensive pattern written as if it were very cheap to compute. If you want to do this, write it as a guard clause, where you can make it clear exactly what's happening.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to advise against something because of performance reasons when the question doesn't have any interest in performance - premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: Feel free to do slow things all you want. My answer recommends doing exactly those slow things...but do them in a guard, where you can *see* that they're expensive.

Comment: That's still coding with performance in mind when performance is not yet an issue - who cares that this is expensive? You don't even know if this code is going to be shared in a way that means the person reading it wouldn't know the behaviour of the "pattern match".

Answer (score 0):

This is *almost* possible with TemplateHaskell - someone more experienced with it could improve on this answer.

```hs
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

(+++) :: Q Pat -> String -> Q Pat
x +++ y = [p| ((\string -> splitAt (length string - length y) string) -> (x, $literal_pattern)) |]
  where literal_pattern = returnQ (LitP (StringL y))
```

This is usable in the pattern position, and you can pass in a pattern as the first argument using TemplateHaskell's quasiquoting:

```hs
f $([p|x|] +++ "bar") = x
```

Rather annoyingly, I can't find any explanation of how you can pass a pattern to a TemplateHaskell splice any more succintly than this.

Comment: I would advise against using TH for trivial tasks like this. Besides hurting readability, it also impacts compile times. Also, your `+++` is plain wrong - it forgets to check that the suffix matches! Instead of a hitting non-exhaustive cases error, `f "hello"` happily returns `"he"`. That's because `ViewPatterns` introduces a new `y` variable instead of asserting it is equal to your outer `y`. IMO, the complexity of this solution outweighs the small syntactic benefit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I was a bit naive with the quasiquoting mechanics. The updated version works. But I don't think readability or compile times are important enough to discount these kinds of solutions unless the person asking says so. The question is about the syntactic benefit - that's what I want to answer.