# How to split a String at white-spaces, which are not escaped?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I'd like to split my String at the non escaped white-spaces like this:

```
let s = "number\\ 1 number\\ 2 number\\ 3"


["number\\ 1", "number\\ 2", "number\\ 3"]

or even better

["number 1", "number 2", "number 3"]
```

How would I have to do this?

Attempt 1:

```hs
let s = "number\\ 1 number\\ 2 number\\ 3"

splitWhitespace :: String -> [String]
splitWhitespcae s = splitOn " " s
-- returns ["number\\","1","number\\","2","number\\","3"]

concatBackslash :: [String] -> [String]
concatBackslash [] = []
concatBackslash (x : xx : xs) = case init x of
    "\\" -> (x ++ xx) : concatBackslash xs
    _ -> x : xx : concatBackslash x
```

But for some reason this returns the same List.

Attempt 2:

```hs
splitOnWhitespace :: String -> [String]
splitOnWhitespace s = splitOn " " s

concatBackslash :: [String] -> [String]
concatBackslash [] = []
concatBackslash [x, xs] = case last x of
    '\\' -> [(init x) ++ xs]
    _ -> [x, xs]
concatBackslash (x : xx : xs) = case last x of
    '\\' -> concatBackslash (((init x) ++ xx) : xs)
    _ -> x: concatBackslash (xx : xs)
```

This was done with the help of @leftaroundabout, however I did end without my whitespaces.

```
> let s = "number\\ 1 number\\ 2 number\\ 3"
> concatBackslash $ splitOnWhitespace s
["number1","number2","number3"]
```

Comment: That is not valid Haskell code. I suppose you mean `s = "number\\ 1 num..."`, or IOW, the _raw contents_ of `s` are `number\ 1` etc.?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.

Comment: Ok. But you also should some own effort at solving the problem. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I posted my attempt

Comment: We have excellent parser combinator libraries in which this would be completely painless. Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52556531/791604) for an idea of what parser code can look like with one of these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- `init` gives you everything *except* the last character in a string. But when you're trying to match with `"\\"`, that would be *verily* the last character. So, you should actually use `last` in the case statement.
- Where you do need `init` however is when `++`ing that element together with the next one. It is in that case that you do not want to keep the trailing `\` but all before it.

Comment: I adapted your tips and got it half working, however I ended up without my white-spaces... Could you please have a look at my second attempt?

Comment: Well, you've split away the whitespaces unconditionally at the beginning. Either you need to change the splitting function, or put whitespaces back in where you're processing the `\ ` symbols.